# Creating a Grid Layout using React

Tags: css, reactjs, gridview, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have an array of objects and I want to display them in 6 Rows and 3 Cols Grid. I am using the following code.

```
 const GridLayout = (props) => {
        let layout = [];
        let total_articles = props.articles.length;
        let nRows = total_articles / 3;
        let nCols = 3;

        for (let i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
            layout.push(<div className="row">);
            for (let j = 0; j < nCols && (i * nCols) + j < total_articles; j++) {
                    layout.push(
                    <div key={(i * nCols) + j} className="col-md-4 column">
                        <ArticleCard articleDetails={props.articles[(i * nCols) + j]}/>
                    </div>)
            }
                layout.push(</div>);
        }
        return (
            <div id={"mainContent"} className="container">
                {layout}
            </div>
        )
    };
```

The first and last layout.push() are causing an issue and giving me a syntax error. If i remove them it works but just adds all the articles in one row, while I want it in 6 different rows.

I have a feeling I might have over complicated this and there must be a better way to accomplish the same thing, so would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is typically used to [`render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) lists in React.

As for gridding your layout; you might find [`CSS Grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) [useful](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid).

See below for a practical example.

```
const GridLayout = (props) => (
   <div id="mainContent" className="container" style={{display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, 1fr)', gridGap: '10px', gridAutoRows: 'minMax(100px, auto)'}}>
     {this.props.articles.map((article) => (
       <div>
         <ArticleCard articleDetails={article}/>
       </div>
     ))}
   </div>
)
```